# SwiftUI doesn't refresh until button action finishes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want the view to be updated every time @State list gets updated.
But when I use Button to trigger a consecutive update, the list gets updated only after all the consecutive updates are finished.

This code updates the list 10 seconds after the button is pressed.
What should I do to make this code update every second?

```
@State var i_list: [Int] = []

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            for i in 0..<10 {
                i_list.append(i)
                do {
                    sleep(1)
                }
            }
        }) {
            Text(button_text)
        }
        
        List (i_list, id: \.self){ i in
            Text(String(i))
        }
    }
}
```

---

Solved:

I solved this problem by updating the list in a different thread.

```
let globalQueue = DispatchQueue.global()
globalQueue.async {
    for i in 0..<10 {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            i_list.append(i)
        }
        do {
            sleep(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sleep` blocks the main thread,  so the UI can't update.  Don't use `sleep`

Comment: @Paulw11 `sleep` is just an example to simplify the code. I perform other work between the list updates and it works the same way.

Comment: Ok, then you need to show code that is more representative of your problem, since `sleep` is the cause of the issue in this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your view updates immediately, instead of using a for loop to update your array, use a publisher. Here I use a timer and add a `onReceive(timer)` on the `List`

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var i_list: [Int] = []
    @State var currentNumber = 0
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List (i_list, id: \.self) { i in
                Text(String(i))
            }.onReceive(timer) { _ in
                guard currentNumber < 10 else {
                    return
                }
                i_list.append(currentNumber)
                currentNumber += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: changed currentNumber to @State